# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Tags: java, jsp

I am using eclipse 3.2 tomcat server 5.5. I am implementing a system in a college.

I have a problem in my jsp codes. When i run the program the error are: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
An error occurred at line: 1,524 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block


An error occurred at line: 1,534 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token


An error occurred at line: 1,535 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

however, my codes only got only about 12++ lines. Why would this happen? Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Show us your sample code please.

Comment: There is some tag closing problem in jsp, Or if you use any custom tag the value will not pass correctly. post your jsp code

Comment: If the question is why the message says line 1500+ while there are only about 12 lines of source code: the JSP is first used to generate a Java file which might have those 1500 codes (because of boilerplate code which is added).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the response, my codes about 12++ lines, will you really go through my codes?

Comment: you have simple missing or not matching parenthesis. Please do not post 1200+ line of codes here.

Comment: it is 1200++ lines, and during compiling the codes, it has no error. but when i run the program, this error come out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced similar behavior of eclipse, too. Although the code was correct it printed this error message. Try to clean the project, or restart the eclipse. That solve the problem for me.

Comment: thank you for your help. But it still does not work. the same error come out.

Comment: And you are sure that your code is correct and there is really no } missing?

Comment: working already.. i need to restart my eclipse 3 times after clean project, thanks a lot :DD

Comment: You're welcome! Eclipse is acting weird sometimes... :D

Comment: I've switched to IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains and I like it more than Eclipse. You might want to give it a try. It's a bit different, but easier to use IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and try to run it again.This is because of cache. Some time it shows this behavior.